# What is the correct name for a non-whole real number?

Tags: terminology, real-numbers

I apologise for the simple nature of this question but I can't find the answer.

I know that a whole number is an integer. I also know that a number that can be expressed as the quotient of two integers is a rational number and its counterpart is an irrational number.

What I don't know is what is the correct term for any real number that is not an integer? I.e: what's the generic term for either a rational or an irrational number?

Examples of what I have in mind are

$$1.5, \quad
3.14317567567, \quad
2.01, \quad \text{etc.}
$$

Comment: I believe it is called a [non-integer](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/non-integer).

Comment: Rational numbers include integers, so "the generic term for either a rational or an irrational number" isn't quite what you're looking for. The set of interest is $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z$, not sure of a pithy name for its elements.

Comment: It may be worth specifying further by calling it a non-integer *real number* so that it isn't confused with $\Bbb C\setminus \Bbb Z$ or similar.

Comment: Real, non-integer.

Comment: The adjectival form is probably "non-integral", as in "a non-integral real number".

Comment: Non integral! I think that's the term I'll use. This is for a grammar specification for a programming language and that seems to be the term that Microsoft have adopted. Thank you everybody.

Comment: The more common name for "whole numbers" (apparently translated from the german "ganze Zahl") is "integer" , then "non-integer" is the obvious name for the other numbers.

Comment: @JMoravitz It is not unnatural to consider $1+i$ as a "non-integer" as well, although usually the real non-integers are meant.